# Converting data from wide to frequency counts of columns

Tags: r, plyr

I have data from subjects currently structured like

```
df <- data.frame(subject.ID = 1:6, 
      questionA = as.factor(c("SA", "A", "D", "SD", "A", "N")), 
      questionB = as.factor(c("A", "A", "D", "SD", "A", "N")), 
      questionC = as.factor(c("SA", "A", "A", "SD", "A", "SD")))
```

what is the most elegant way to convert it to a data frame with each row including the question and the frequencies of the 5 response options? i.e.

```
> 
    Question     SA        A       N       D        SD
1   questionA     1        2       1       1        1
2   questionB     0        3       1       1        1
3   questionC     1        3       0       0        2
```

I've tried working with small subset of the data (just question A) and using plyr's count function before transposing it and relabeling the columns (i.e.:

```
temp2 <- count(df, c("questionA"))
questionName <- "questionA"
responseNames <- temp2$questionA
temp2 <- as.data.frame(t(temp2[,-1]))
colnames(temp2) <- responseNames
temp2$question <- questionName
```

It does work for the most part, but it's not ideal (single question at a time which means rbinding all them back together and incredibly clumsy) and it doesn't include the 0 frequency categories.  What is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(melt(df, id.vars = 'subject.ID'), variable ~ value)
#     variable A D N SA SD
# 1: questionA 2 1 1  1  1
# 2: questionB 3 1 1  0  1
# 3: questionC 3 0 0  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `recast` from `reshape2` which is a convenient wrapper for `melt/dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, id.var = "subject.ID", variable ~ value)
#   variable A D N SA SD
#1 questionA 2 1 1  1  1
#2 questionB 3 1 1  0  1
#3 questionC 3 0 0  1  2
```